# XMPPFramework - Add Buddy in Openfire

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

We are creating a chat application using **XMPP** and **Openfire**. We have to create a new **social community** which allows users to chat. We have established the connection using XMPP with Openfire. We are also able to get the chats and online presence of users.

My question is, can we add friends using XMPP?

I searched and found out about the `XMPPRoster` (section 8.2 in XMPP RFC). However, I didn't get a clear understanding how I could add friends from the database list using XMPP.

I've installed the 'subscription' plug in and customized it, but the following delegate method is not getting called:

`- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceiveBuddyRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence`

If anyone has an idea, please do help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check this link.Hope it will helps you http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html